# spring social client ajax login provider

Tags: facebook, cordova, spring-security, spring-social, childbrowser

### The Story:

I am looking for some social integration experts to enlighten me this puzzle here.
My web server is using spring security to authenticate user signin,signup. I recently implemented spring social in my web server, all went very smooth. Take fb as example, when user login from facebook, spring social will build outh url and redirect user to facebook. Once user authenticated in facebook, it will redirect them back to my site.

### The Puzzle:

I need to implement my mobile app(html5 + phonegap) having same "login" capability. I went though the facebook integration page. There are a few way to do authentication for html5 app. I chose the server side implementation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ over client side login, because I still need spring assist to check if email exist in my web server, redirect signup page otherwise.

The first problem I encounter is redirect in mobile app, I need pop up window to redirect to provider login page instead of app window. I managed to get redirect url through ajax call and open new window in childbrowser phonegap plugin. Now the problem is when user authenticated through provider, there is no easy way for server to inform "user authenticated" to client because it is in separated browser.

#### sample code

```
onFBlogin: function(){
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: APP.domain + "api/mobile/signin/facebook.json",
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(result, request) {
    var json = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
         window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function (url) {
            if(url==APP.domain+"api/mobile/success"){
            window.plugins.childBrowser.close();
            }
    };
    window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(json.outhurl,{ showLocationBar: true });
    },
    failure: function(result, request) {
          console.log("request facebook signin redirect url" + result);
    },
});
}
```

Normally, in spring security if user authenticated through my rest api, client can post request and getting authenticated token through successful call back. I can reuse those tokens for each rest api call. According to above code. I am not able to know if the authentication completed and when should I send token from server to client.

I'd appreciated if you could throw me some idea. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing the same problem. I am about to try to implement this:

Configure your app in Facebook so as the return addres is something like http:// what ever dot com/receiveFacebookResponse
which basically responses a javascript code to be executed on the just opened pop-up. This js code will close the pop-up and execute a function on is parent window (the one with your app). This function must exist in your app. You put it (with all its parameters) in the session (or cookie). This funcion should do an ajax call to change the header of your app, basically to change the "login here" message to "Hello logged-user" (as well as many other things you may need) and, very probably, to complete the action that was started but the login process interrupted.

I'll try and I'll tell you. I'll be glad to hear if you did it some other way.

Comment: Hi Oscar. Did you actually implement this? Try to make your answers to offer concrete guidance. Also, you could improve your writing and make it more clear.